# Java GUI - Buffered Reader only reads the last line when I press a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, bufferedreader

Basically, I have a jFrame where some data is supposed to show inside whenever I press a button. The data is being taken from different files and the way I want it to work is whenever I press the same button for a file to show me different lines, however it always shows the last line of the file. I would like to add that I am also using a Tokenizer, even though I'm not sure if it is relevant.

I've tried using loops and numbering the lines but it doesn't really work.

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Stoke
        //Protocol - 555
        String fileName="Stoke.txt";
        int lineNumber=0;
          try
       {
           FileReader fin=new FileReader(fileName);
           BufferedReader din=new BufferedReader(fin);
            System.out.println("Data in the file "+fileName+" is ");
            //read from the file
            String line=null; //line of text

            while((line=din.readLine())!=null && lineNumber<1){
                    //here we have read in a line of text
                    //now parase line to extract data and print it out to the screen
                    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");

                    String location=st.nextToken().trim();
                    String gps=st.nextToken().trim();
                    String humidity=st.nextToken().trim();
                    String temperature=st.nextToken().trim();
                    String dateNtime=st.nextToken().trim();

                    weatherTable.setText(location+"\n"+gps+"\n"+humidity+"\n"+temperature+"\n"+dateNtime+"\n");
            }

           din.close(); //close the stream
```

I am expecting the application to show different lines whenever i press jButton5 but it always shows the last line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You set **lineNumber** to **0** initially, and never update it...

but you use it in your while loop condition as **lineNumber<1**, which means the condition is never failing, until you reach the end of the file, where **(line=din.readLine())!=null** returns false, and you exit with the last line in the buffer.

You have to figure out a way to count lines, then **randomize** on **[0..numberOfLines]** if you want to ouput a random line only, or append instead of set on 
**weatherTable.setText(location+"\n"+gps+"\n"+humidity+"\n"+temperature+"\n"+dateNtime+"\n");**
if you want the entire file to be set.